# convertir bitmap a array de bytes

Tags: android, bitmap

intento convertir un archivo bitmap en android, a un array de bytes para luego pasarlo a un web service asmx, y desde est guardarlo en una base de datos sql, pero me da error de compatibilidad, alguien sabria como puedo hacerlo??

Comment: Bienvenido edita la pregunta y muestra tus avances del codigo que tienes ya!!

Comment: Hola juanjo, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Tal y como está redactada la pregunta es demasiado amplia y hace falta más información para poder ayudarte: ¿qué has intentado hasta el momento? ¿qué error exacto recibes y en qué parte de tu código? Lee [ask] y [mcve] para más información y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

La mejor forma de convertir un bitmap a un array de bytes es la siguiente:

```
Bitmap bmp = intent.getExtras().get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
bmp.recycle();
```

Prueba a ver si de esta forma no tienes problemas.